# What is the best way to store Data as long as Tomcat works

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have to decide how and where I want to save a list of Server information.
What I want to achieve is to init an application which is working with `Hibernate`. Every time it maps a database it has to save the database-name, the Url and some other data.

Can anyone suggest a fast way how to save, update and read data in this case? And what kind of data structure I should use?

I am free to choose any design or third party library I want (e.g. Properties, Spring Beans etc.). My main task is to decide which of those to us and to motivate why.

I'm currently working with `Spring`, `Hibernate` and `Java 7`.

Comment: Information about the current application is typically stored in the `ServletContext`.

Comment: For this one i have to get a Http Request but on that Part i dont get one, as far as i got it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I don't get how the question title and message relate to one another. And what do you mean by _as long as Tomcat works_? How would it possibly 'work' otherwise?

Comment: I mean i need to store Data as long a Tomcat works. When he's down then the Data has to get lost and as long as Tomcat Server is Online he need so store the Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is to create a Singleton class that stores my Data and get cleared by a restart. Thank you all very much for your answers